# Relation on the determinant of a matrix and the product of its diagonal entries?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

Let $A$ be a $3\times 3$ symmetric matrix, with three real eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$, and diagonal entries $a_1,a_2,a_3$, is it true that
\begin{equation*}
\det A=\lambda_1\lambda_2\lambda_3\geq a_1a_2a_3\ ?
\end{equation*}

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you want absolute values?  Otherwise $\begin{bmatrix}1&2&0\\2&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$ would be a counterexample.  Do you want to assume invertibility?  Otherwise the matrix with all $1$s is a counterexample.

Comment: Thank you very much for your examples! I don't want absolute values or invertible matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a positive definite counterexample:  $$\begin{bmatrix}2&1&0\\1&2&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}.$$